# pushing object to an array giving me empty array

Tags: javascript, arrays

hi all i have this code where i select data from a database and want to insert them as objects inside an array :

```
conn2.query('SELECT date, action FROM actions WHERE ?', [{
  issue_id: data.id
}], function(error, data2) {
  if (error) {
    showNotification('Error :' + error, 'danger', 'glyphicon glyphicon-tasks');
  } else {
    data2.forEach(function(data21) {
      res.push({
        "date": data21.date,
        "description": data21.action
      });
      console.log(res);
    });
  }
});
```

the problem is that the res is alwayes empty .... 
if i

```
console.log({"date": data21.date,"description": data21.action})
```

it give me the right object .... seems that the push is not write.

**Edited:** thanks every body i could't solve this problem so i used officegen which did the job nicely

Comment: are you seeing any errors in console?

Comment: Maybe the query returns noting and ``data2`` is an empty array, thus ``res.push`` never gets called? Add ``console.log('data2', data2)`` to the beginning of the callback function.

Comment: ![data](http://imageshack.com/a/img921/1061/wEou7s.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you must have not declared res as an array object
res = []
Or maybe the data2 is empty

Comment: console.log({"date": data21.date,"description": data21.action})

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

```
res.push({date: data21.date,description: data21.action});
console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
console.log(res.toString());
```